# Strange exception happening only after some hours of production

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

This exception appears only after some hours that my spring boot app runs as backend, if i restart it disappears. Any hint?

```
2018-Mar-06 16:13:09.388 DEBUG [http-nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/query/ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter
```

Comment: You would need to understand what is causing the NoClassDefFoundError https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: Also some insight as to how to clear the error http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Comment: Also your question does not include what you are trying to do and how you have setup your spring boot project.

Comment: Have you checked if that class is in your fat jar? java classes are loaded on-demand by the class loader so an infrequently used class may take some time to show up as an exception.